# Is it possible to disable the audio of a specific application using Jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, music

I have a game on my iPhone that always interrupts my music even if I turn the volume down to zero (every 30 seconds or so). Is there some kind of a workaround that lets me continue playing music? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're JailBroken, install and open up iFile from Cydia. Navigate to `/var/mobile/Applications/`, tap the gear in the bottom-left corner and make sure "Application Names" is set to `On`, and then find the app you mentioned inside that folder. To completely disable audio from that app, you're going to need to delete every audio file inside that folder (and subfolders). It might take you a while, but that's the only way to do what you want without writing your own JailBreak tweak. If the app you're muting is written poorly, it may  crash when it cannot find those files you deleted. If this is the case, just reinstall the app, and you won't be able to mute it until somebody nice comes along and writes a tweak.

Comment: yes. replace them with empty audio files

Comment: That would require a bit more work, but that's another great solution.